# Mysql complex query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can anyone help me in this query ?

Having table structure like this :

```
id |Attribute | value 
-------------------
 1 |name      | user1
 2 | id       |    100
 3 |name      | user2
 4 | id       | 101
 5 |name      | user1
 6 | id       | 103
```

I want output like this :

```
name | id 
------------
user1 | 100
user2 | 102
user3 | 103
```

Comment: Your table structure gives me nightmares at night.

Comment: How do you tell what id is associated with name?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` and `name` records always interleave:

```
SELECT  mn.value, mi.value
FROM    mytable mn
JOIN    mytable mi
ON      mi.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mii
        WHERE   mii.attribute = 'id'
                AND mii.id > mn.id
        ORDER BY
                mii.id
        LIMIT 1
        )
WHERE   mn.attribute = 'name'
```

I don't even dare to ask whose idea was to design a table like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into case when to reorder this "structure" somehow. 
maybe something like helps... Haven't checked that. Basically I am just suggesting CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT attribute,value 
MAX(CASE when (Attribute = name) then value end) AS name
MAX(CASE when (Attribute = id) then value end) AS id
FROM table
```